# Can I Parse time in d3 in this format "%H%M"?

Tags: d3.js, datetime-parsing

Hiii,

I have a time with this format `hhmm`, like this : 2010

I have tried this :

```
var timeFormat = d3.time.format("%H%M");
d.Dep_Time1= timeFormat.parse(d.Dep_Time1);
```

But it does not work ... :s

Please how can I achieve the above ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is converting your 4-digit number to a string, in such a way that D3 knows how to parse it:

```js
var times = [2210, 2315, 0817, 1456];
var timeFormat = d3.time.format("%H%M");

times.forEach(function(time){
    time = timeFormat.parse(time.toString());
    console.log(time);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

PS: edit based on @altocumulus comment (see below).

Comment: Why complicate matters by fiddling around with substrings and insert new characters? Just `use time = timeFormat.parse(time.toString());`, leave the format specifier at `"%H%M"` and you are done.